# Running simple Open Policy Agent Playground example from CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, open-policy-agent

It's not clear to me how to run the Simple Example from the Open Policy Agent Playground from the CLI.

**play.rego**

```
package play
default hello = false

hello {
    m := input.message
    m == "world"
}
```

**input.json**

```
{
    "message": "world"
}
```

**I tried using:**

```
opa eval -i input.json -d play.rego "data.play.hello"
```

**But**, I could **not** get this result

```
{
    "hello": true
}
```

**Unfortunately**, I got this: **:(**

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "expressions": [
        {
          "value": true,
          "text": "data.play.hello",
          "location": {
            "row": 1,
            "col": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I thought others might find it useful to understand how to run these example from the CLI, so I had to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a great question! Unless "evaluate selection" is selected, the Rego Playground always evaluates the entire policy, i.e. all rules included. When you query a policy using `opa eval` you can either choose to do the same, or as you do in your example - query just a single rule for its value.

If you change the query from `"data.play.hello"` to just `"data.play"` it will evaluate the full policy just like the playground:

```sh
$ opa eval -i input.json -d play.rego "data.play"
{
  "result": [
    {
      "expressions": [
        {
          "value": {
            "hello": true
          },
          "text": "data.play",
          "location": {
            "row": 1,
            "col": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If you only want to display the actual output without all the details around it, you could use one of the formatting options available for `opa eval` such as `--format raw`:

```sh
$ opa eval --format raw -i input.json -d play.rego "data.play"
{"hello":true}
```

Comment: Thanks. It turns out --format raw is not supported, but --format pretty works ! This worked for me [opa eval --format pretty -i input.json -d play.rego "data.play"]. I put up a github repo if anyone might want to try this.  https://github.com/pmcdowell-okta/opa-example

Comment: Ah, yeah, the raw output format was added in a recent version of OPA.